# Number of permutations (with repetition) that adhere to precedence

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Similar to another question that has been asked - I am looking for an equation to find a number of "viable permutations" that adhere to a rule of precedence. Lets say given set $S$ with (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), how many permutations with $N$ trials would have a $7$ come after a $6$, which comes after a $5$, which comes after a $4$, and so on from $1-7$. They do not need to be immediately following each other, so long as the numbers appear in that order anywhere in the permutation. For example if $N = 15$, the total possible permutations would be $7^{15} = 4.7475615e+12$. I need to know how many of these have a $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ anywhere in the permutation in order, but there can be any random numbers in between them.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: With regards to your question, does the first $1$ need to precede the first $2$ or is a permutation such as $5, \color{blue}{1}, 4, \color{blue}{2}, 6, \color{blue}{3}, 5, \color{blue}{4}, 6, \color{blue}{5}, 7, \color{blue}{6}, \color{blue}{7}, 3, 2$ acceptable?

Comment: No, as long as the sequence appears in that order anywhere in the permutation, it would work. That permutation would be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  While the problem you have stated is interesting, readers of this site generally expect some context for the problem.  What is its source?  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?  What is your mathematical background?  If you were motivated to ask the question by a computer simulation, you should include your code.  Please edit your question to add that context.  If you do so, I expect that your question will be warmly received here.